# Intent for images opens video camera and gives runtime exception for the Uri

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, runtime-error, uri

I made a very simple app in which I can open the videocamera and photocamera through the buttons in the menu. The following is my code for this app:

```
private static final int VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE=1;
private static final int IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE=2;

public void startRecord(){
    Intent videoIntent= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    File dir=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
    Uri fileUri=Uri.fromFile(new File(dir,"myVideo1.mp4"));
    videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
    startActivityForResult(videoIntent,VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
}

public void capturePhoto(){
    Intent imageIntent= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File dir=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    Uri fileUri=Uri.fromFile(new File(dir,"myImage1.jpg"));
    imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    startActivityForResult(imageIntent,IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.action_capture:
        capturePhoto();
    case R.id.action_record:
        startRecord();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode==VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE){
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Video saved to: "+data.getData(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else if(resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Record canceled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Record failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }else if(requestCode==IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE){
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Image saved to: "+data.getData(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else if(resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Image capture canceled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Image capture failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the video works perfectly, but when I try to open the camera for images it automatically opens the videocamera as well. When I press "return" after then the image camera does open, but when I want to take a picture the app shuts down because of the runtime error. It says `failure delivering results to activity... ...attempt to invoke Uri on null object`. I can't find what's wrong with my Uri, so anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Your `switch` is written incorrectly:

```
switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.action_capture:
        capturePhoto();
    case R.id.action_record:
        startRecord();
        return true;
    }
```

When `R.id.action_capture` is chosen, you will call both `capturePhoto()` *and* `startRecord()`, because your `case R.id.action_capture` section does not end with `break` or `return`.

Also note that `data.getData()` is supposed to return `null` for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. You are setting `EXTRA_OUTPUT`; look there for your photo.